# Conditionally merge rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am doing some tricky data cleaning. I have one dataset (first extract below) that is the output from the digitization of pdf tables. Unfortunately columns were not digitized properly. Sometimes, what shall be in column X3 ended up concatenated in column X2 with the last word of column X2...

What I am trying to do is to bring back what should be in column X3 to X3 and collapse the two rows in X2 together.

I have attached an extract of the output I am trying to create.

Any idea about how can I do this?

Thank you!

```
structure(list(X1 = c(111L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 121L, NA, NA, 121L, 
NA, NA, 141L, NA, NA, 141L, NA), X2 = structure(c(7L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"A - BWHITE", "ASMITH", "B - DBURNEY", "Garden Harris", "House M. Aba", 
"House M. Bab", "House M. Cac", "Street M. Bak", "Villa Thomas"
), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A", 
"A - C", "D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

```
structure(list(X1 = c(111L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 121L, NA, NA, 121L, 
NA, NA, 141L, NA, NA, 141L), X2 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("", "Garden Harris WHITE", 
"House M. Aba SMITH", "House M. Bab", "House M. Cac", "Street M. Bak", 
"Villa Thomas BURNEY"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
"A", "A - B", "A - C", "B - D", "D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Follow up question here: [Cleaning extract_tables conditional merge rows, systematic extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609591/cleaning-extract-tables-conditional-merge-rows-systematic-extraction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we could do it:

Credits to MartinGal for the regex "(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+") (upvote!)

1. Replace empty values with `NA`
2. Use `lead` to move rows up in `X3` conditional on `NA` else not
3. filter if is not `NA` in `X1`
4. Extract the important information with  `str_extract` and regex `"(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+"` -> combine this info with column `X2` with `str_c` and finally `coalesce` both.
5. Remove the string to keep relevant one with regex and `str_remove`

```
library(dyplr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~sub("^\\s*$", NA, .)),
           X3= ifelse(is.na(X3), lead(X2), X3)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(X1)) %>% 
    mutate(X2 = coalesce(str_c(X2," ", str_extract(X3, "(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+")), X2),
           X3 = str_remove_all(X3, "(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+"))
```

Output:

```
   X1                  X2    X3
1 111        House M. Bab     A
2   2        House M. Cac A - C
3 121       Street M. Bak     D
4 121  House M. Aba SMITH     A
5 141 Garden Harris WHITE A - B
6 141 Villa Thomas BURNEY B - D
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(X2 != "") %>% 
  mutate(
    extract_name = lead(str_extract(X2, "(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+")),
    extract_part = lead(str_extract(X2, "[A-Z](\\s-\\s[A-Z]){0,1}(?=[A-Z]+)")),
    new_X2 = ifelse(!is.na(extract_name), paste(X2, extract_name), as.character(X2)),
    new_X3 = ifelse(X3 != "", as.character(X3), extract_part)
    ) %>% 
  drop_na(X1) %>% 
  select(-extract_name, -extract_part)
```

which returns

```r
   X1            X2    X3              new_X2 new_X3
1 111  House M. Bab     A        House M. Bab      A
2   2  House M. Cac A - C        House M. Cac  A - C
3 121 Street M. Bak     D       Street M. Bak      D
4 121  House M. Aba        House M. Aba SMITH      A
5 141 Garden Harris       Garden Harris WHITE  A - B
6 141  Villa Thomas       Villa Thomas BURNEY  B - D
```

**Note:** I don't think this approach is really stable regarding the regex used. For readability I filtered out some annoying rows containing `NA` and empty strings, you should remove those parts if necessary.

Comment: Much cleaner than mine (+1)

Comment: It's the power of `dplyr` (et al), but you need this package. I'm a fan of `base R`-solution since they are more "pure", but that lies beyond my basic understanding of `R`.

Comment: I think you're understating your regex, it's terrific.

Comment: That is just awesome!

Comment: @MartinGal, this is a good answer. Your regex helped me to finish my version (upvote!).

Answer (score 1):

This is a yucky one:

```
# Retype the data and nullify empty values;
# use X1 as a key: intermediateResult => data.frame
intermediateResult <- data.frame(
  lapply(
    transform(
      replace(df, df == "", NA_character_),
      X1 = na.omit(X1)[cumsum(!is.na(X1))]
    ),
    as.character
  )
)

# Re-structure the data: 
# interemdiateResult2 => data.frame
intermediateResult2 <- do.call(
  rbind,
  Filter(
    function(y){
      nrow(y) > 0
    },
    Map(
      function(x){
        z <- x[!is.na(x$X2),]
        if(nrow(z) > 1 & is.na(z$X3[1])){
          z$X3[1] <- z$X2[2]
          head(z, 1)
        }else{
          z
        }
      },
      with(
        intermediateResult, 
        split(
          intermediateResult, 
          paste(
            X1,
            cumsum(
              (is.na(X2)
            )
          ),
          sep = " - "
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Regex it and hope for the best: 
# result => data.frame
result <- data.frame(
  transform(
    intermediateResult2,
    X2 = paste0(
      X2, 
      ifelse(
        (nchar(X3) == 1 | grepl("^\\w\\s+-\\s+\\w$", X3)),
        "",
        ifelse(
          !(grepl("^\\w\\s+-\\s+\\w", X3)),
          paste0(" ", substr(X3, 2, nchar(X3))),
          paste0(" ", gsub("(^\\w\\s+-\\s+\\w)(.*)", "\\2", X3))
        )
      )
    ),
    X3 = ifelse(
      nchar(X3) == 1 | grepl("^\\w\\s+-\\s+\\w$", X3) , 
      X3,
      ifelse(
        !(grepl("^\\w\\s+-\\s+\\w", X3)),
        substr(X3, 1, 1),
        gsub("(^\\w\\s+-\\s+\\w)(.*)", "\\1", X3)
        )
      )
    ),
  row.names = NULL
)
```