# Cleaning extract_tables conditional merge rows, systematic extraction

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is a follow up from this previous post: [Conditionally merge rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602693/conditionally-merge-rows)

I digitized all tables of this 1838 pages long [PDF document](https://www.ceni.cd/assets/bundles/documents/cadre-legal/cadre-legal_1545812547.pdf) using extract_tables from `tabulizer` package (I had to do it page by page because of memory issue).

```
for (i in seq(1:1868)){
  
  # Location of CENI pdf file
  location <- paste0("data/presidential_elections/cadre_legal/cadre-legal_1545812547-page",i,".pdf")
  
  extract <- as.data.frame(extract_tables(location), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

  result[[i]] <- extract %>%
  mutate(page = i) 
  
}

temp <-bind_rows(result)
```

Unfortunately, the output is very messy. Specifically, there are several issues that I am not able to fix properly:

1. When in input `Nom du site de vote` expands over two lines in a cell, then, in the output, `Nom du site de vote` and `Secteur/Chefferie/Commune` concatenate in a single variable. In the output, the cell below `Nom du site de vote` concatenates `Plage` and the second line of `Nom du site de vote`.
2. When in input `Groupement/Quartier` is missing, then, in the output, `Adresse (Village/Avenue)` and `Nbre CV` are in the same column.
3. When in input `Adresse (Village/Avenue)` expands over two lines, then, in the output, `Plage`, the second line of `Adresse (Village/Avenue)` and `Nbre CV` are all concatenated in the same cell.
4. For reasons I can't explain sometimes `Groupement/Quartier` and `Adresse (Village/Avenue)` concatenate in the same column.
5. For X reason, sometimes, `Nom du site de vote` and `Secteur/Chefferie/Commune` concatenate under `Nom du site de vote`.

Here is my cleaning code:

```
final <- temp %>%
  
  # Remove list of words coming from table header
  filter((X1!="N°")) %>%
  filter((X2!="/Commune")) %>%
  filter((X2!="/Commune /Quartier")) %>%
  filter((X3!="/Commune")) %>%
  filter((X3!="/Commune /Quartier")) %>%
  filter((X4!="/Commune")) %>%
  
  # Lag by a factor of 1 column X1
  mutate(X1=lag(X1, n=1)) %>%
  
  # Replace page=blank if X1=blank
  #mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
  #        mutate(page = if_else(X1 == "", "", page))) %>%
  
  # When XN spans over two lines then XN is concatenate XN and Plage (L1XN / Plage|L2XN)
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
          mutate(Plage = case_when(str_detect(X6, "A - B") ~ "A - B",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - C") ~ "A - C",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - D") ~ "A - D",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - E") ~ "A - E",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - F") ~ "A - F",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - G") ~ "A - G",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - H") ~ "A - H",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - I") ~ "A - I",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - J") ~ "A - J",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - K") ~ "A - K",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - L") ~ "A - L",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - M") ~ "A - M",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - N") ~ "A - N",
                                   str_detect(X6, "A - O") ~ "A - O",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - B") ~ "A - B",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - C") ~ "A - C",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - D") ~ "A - D",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - E") ~ "A - E",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - F") ~ "A - F",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - G") ~ "A - G",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - H") ~ "A - H",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - I") ~ "A - I",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - J") ~ "A - J",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - K") ~ "A - K",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - L") ~ "A - L",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - M") ~ "A - M",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - N") ~ "A - N",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - O") ~ "A - O",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - P") ~ "A - P",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - Q") ~ "A - Q",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - R") ~ "A - R",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - S") ~ "A - S",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - T") ~ "A - T",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - U") ~ "A - U",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - V") ~ "A - V",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - W") ~ "A - W",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - X") ~ "A - X",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - Y") ~ "A - Y",
                                   str_detect(X5, "A - Z") ~ "A - Z",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - B") ~ "A - B",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - C") ~ "A - C",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - D") ~ "A - D",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - E") ~ "A - E",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - F") ~ "A - F",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - G") ~ "A - G",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - H") ~ "A - H",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - I") ~ "A - I",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - J") ~ "A - J",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - K") ~ "A - K",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - L") ~ "A - L",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - M") ~ "A - M",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - N") ~ "A - N",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - O") ~ "A - O",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - P") ~ "A - P",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - Q") ~ "A - Q",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - R") ~ "A - R",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - S") ~ "A - S",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - T") ~ "A - T",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - U") ~ "A - U",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - V") ~ "A - V",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - W") ~ "A - W",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - X") ~ "A - X",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - Y") ~ "A - Y",
                                   str_detect(X4, "A - Z") ~ "A - Z",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - B") ~ "A - B",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - C") ~ "A - C",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - D") ~ "A - D",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - E") ~ "A - E",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - F") ~ "A - F",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - G") ~ "A - G",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - H") ~ "A - H",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - I") ~ "A - I",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - J") ~ "A - J",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - K") ~ "A - K",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - L") ~ "A - L",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - M") ~ "A - M",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - N") ~ "A - N",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - O") ~ "A - O",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - P") ~ "A - P",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - Q") ~ "A - Q",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - R") ~ "A - R",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - S") ~ "A - S",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - T") ~ "A - T",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - U") ~ "A - U",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - V") ~ "A - V",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - W") ~ "A - W",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - X") ~ "A - X",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - Y") ~ "A - Y",
                                   str_detect(X3, "A - Z") ~ "A - Z",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - B") ~ "A - B",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - C") ~ "A - C",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - D") ~ "A - D",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - E") ~ "A - E",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - F") ~ "A - F",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - G") ~ "A - G",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - H") ~ "A - H",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - I") ~ "A - I",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - J") ~ "A - J",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - K") ~ "A - K",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - L") ~ "A - L",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - M") ~ "A - M",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - N") ~ "A - N",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - O") ~ "A - O",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - P") ~ "A - P",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - Q") ~ "A - Q",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - R") ~ "A - R",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - S") ~ "A - S",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - T") ~ "A - T",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - U") ~ "A - U",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - V") ~ "A - V",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - W") ~ "A - W",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - X") ~ "A - X",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - Y") ~ "A - Y",
                                   str_detect(X2, "A - Z") ~ "A - Z",
                                    X12 != "" & !is.na(X12) ~ X12,
                                    X11 != "" & !is.na(X11) & is.na(X12) ~ X11,
                                    X10 != "" & !is.na(X10) & is.na(X11) & is.na(X12) ~ X10,
                                    X9 != "" & !is.na(X9) & is.na(X10) & is.na(X11) & is.na(X12) ~ X9,
                                    X8 != "" & !is.na(X8) & is.na(X9) & is.na(X10) & is.na(X11) & is.na(X12) ~ X8,
                                    X7 != "" & !is.na(X7) & is.na(X8) & is.na(X9) & is.na(X10) & is.na(X11) & is.na(X12) ~ X7))) %>%

  # Remove pattern in XN
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - B")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - C")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - D")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - E")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - F")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - G")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - H")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - I")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - J")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - K")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - L")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - M")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - N")) %>%
  mutate(X6 = str_remove(X6, "A - O")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - B")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - C")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - D")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - E")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - F")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - G")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - H")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - I")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - J")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - K")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - L")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - M")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - N")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - O")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - P")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - Q")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - R")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - S")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - T")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - U")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - V")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - W")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - X")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - Y")) %>%
  mutate(X5 = str_remove(X5, "A - Z")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - B")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - C")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - D")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - E")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - F")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - G")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - H")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - I")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - J")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - K")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - L")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - M")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - N")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - O")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - P")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - Q")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - R")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - S")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - T")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - U")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - V")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - W")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - X")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - Y")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = str_remove(X4, "A - Z")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - B")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - C")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - D")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - E")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - F")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - G")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - H")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - I")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - J")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - K")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - L")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - M")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - N")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - O")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - P")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - Q")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - R")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - S")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - T")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - U")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - V")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - W")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - X")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - Y")) %>%
  mutate(X3 = str_remove(X3, "A - Z")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - B")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - C")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - D")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - E")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - F")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - G")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - H")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - I")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - J")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - K")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - L")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - M")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - N")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - O")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - P")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - Q")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - R")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - S")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - T")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - U")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - V")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - W")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - X")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - Y")) %>%
  mutate(X2 = str_remove(X2, "A - Z")) %>%
  
  # Adjust Plage when less than 26 SV
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
           mutate(`Plage` = if_else((is.na(`Plage`) & X1 =="" & X2 !=""), substring(X2, 1, 1), `Plage`))) %>%
  
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
           mutate(`Plage` = if_else((is.na(`Plage`) & X1 =="" & X2 =="" & X3 !=""), substring(X3, 1, 1), `Plage`))) %>%

  # Make `Code SV`
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
          mutate(`Code SV` = case_when(X11 != Plage & !is.na(X11) & X11 != "" ~ X11,
                                       X11 == Plage & !is.na(X10) & X10 != "" ~ X10,
                                       X10 == Plage & !is.na(X9) & X9 != "" ~ X9,
                                       X9 == Plage & !is.na(X8) & X8 != "" ~ X8,
                                       X8 == Plage & !is.na(X7) & X7 != "" ~ X7,
                                       X7 == Plage & !is.na(X6) & X6 != "" ~ X6,
                                       X6 == Plage & !is.na(X5) & X5 != "" ~ X5,
                                       X5 == Plage & !is.na(X4) & X4 != "" ~ X4))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
         mutate(`Code SV` = if_else(!is.na(Plage) & (is.na(`Code SV`) | `Code SV`==""), X9, `Code SV`)) %>% 
         mutate(`Code SV` = if_else(!is.na(Plage) & (is.na(`Code SV`) | `Code SV`==""), X8, `Code SV`)) %>%
         mutate(`Code SV` = if_else(!is.na(Plage) & (is.na(`Code SV`) | `Code SV`==""), X7, `Code SV`)) %>%
         mutate(`Code SV` = if_else(!is.na(Plage) & (is.na(`Code SV`) | `Code SV`==""), X6, `Code SV`))) %>%
  
  # Make `Nbre BVD`
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
           mutate(`Nbre BVD` = case_when(X10 == `Code SV` & !is.na(X9) & X9 != "" ~ X9,
                                         X10 == Plage & X9 == `Code SV` & !is.na(X8) & X8 != "" ~ X8,
                                         X9 == Plage & X8 == `Code SV` & !is.na(X7) & X7 != "" ~ X7,
                                         X8 == Plage & X7 == `Code SV` & !is.na(X6) & X6 != "" ~ X6,
                                         X7 == Plage & X6 == `Code SV` & !is.na(X5) & X5 != "" ~ X5,
                                         X6 == Plage & X5 == `Code SV` & !is.na(X4) & X4 != "" ~ X4))) %>%

  # Make `Nbre CV`
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
           mutate(`Nbre CV` = case_when(X9 == `Nbre BVD` & !is.na(X8) & X8 != "" ~ X8,
                                         X9 == `Code SV` & X8 == `Nbre BVD` & !is.na(X7) & X7 != "" ~ X7,
                                         X8 == `Code SV` & X7 == `Nbre BVD` & !is.na(X6) & X6 != "" ~ X6,
                                         X7 == `Code SV` & X6 == `Nbre BVD` & !is.na(X5) & X5 != "" ~ X5,
                                         X6 == `Code SV` & X5 == `Nbre BVD` & !is.na(X4) & X4 != "" ~ X4))) %>%

  # Replace Missing `Nbr BVD`
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
        mutate(`Nbre BVD` = ifelse(is.na(`Nbre BVD`) & X8 == `Code SV`, word(X7, start = -1), `Nbre BVD`)) %>%
        mutate(`Nbre BVD` = ifelse(is.na(`Nbre BVD`) & X7 == `Code SV`, word(X6, start = -1), `Nbre BVD`)) %>%
        mutate(`Nbre BVD` = ifelse(is.na(`Nbre BVD`) & X6 == `Code SV`, word(X5, start = -1), `Nbre BVD`))) %>%
  
  # Replace Missing `Nbre CV`
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
         mutate(`Nbre CV` = ifelse(is.na(`Nbre CV`) & X8 == `Nbre BVD`, word(X7, start = -1), `Nbre CV`)) %>%
         mutate(`Nbre CV` = ifelse(is.na(`Nbre CV`) & X7 == `Nbre BVD`, word(X6, start = -1), `Nbre CV`)) %>%
         mutate(`Nbre CV` = ifelse(is.na(`Nbre CV`) & X6 == `Nbre BVD`, word(X5, start = -1), `Nbre CV`))) %>%
  
  # Replace by blank when XN equals one of the final variables
        mutate(across(everything(), as.character),
              X12 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X12) | X12 != "") & X12 == `Plage`, "", X12), X12),
              X11 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X11) | X11 != "") & X11 == `Plage` | X11 == `Code SV` | X11 == `Nbre BVD` | X11 == `Nbre CV`, "", X11), X11), 
              X10 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X10) | X10 != "") & X10 == `Plage` | X10 == `Code SV` | X10 == `Nbre BVD` | X10 == `Nbre CV`, "", X10), X10),
              X9 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X9) | X9 != "") & X9 == `Plage` | X9 == `Code SV` | X9 == `Nbre BVD` | X9 == `Nbre CV`, "", X9), X9),
              X8 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X8) | X8 != "") & X8 == `Plage` | X8 == `Code SV` | X8 == `Nbre BVD` | X8 == `Nbre CV`, "", X8), X8),
              X7 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X7) | X7 != "") & X7 == `Plage` | X7 == `Code SV` | X7 == `Nbre BVD` | X7 == `Nbre CV`, "", X7), X7),
              X6 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X6) | X6 != "") & X6 == `Plage` | X6 == `Code SV` | X6 == `Nbre BVD` | X6 == `Nbre CV`, "", X6), X6),
              X5 = coalesce(ifelse((!is.na(X5) | X5 != "") & X5 == `Plage` | X5 == `Code SV` | X5 == `Nbre BVD` | X5 == `Nbre CV`, "", X5), X5)) %>%

  # Remove First Letter from X2 and X3
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(X2 = gsub(paste0('^', Plage),'', X2)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(X3 = gsub(paste0('^', Plage),'', X3)) %>%

  # Lag all input variables
  mutate(X1=lag(X1)) %>%
  mutate(X2=lag(X2)) %>%
  mutate(X3=lag(X3)) %>%
  mutate(X4=lag(X4)) %>%
  mutate(X5=lag(X5)) %>%
  mutate(X6=lag(X6)) %>%
  mutate(page=lag(page)) %>%
  
  filter(!(X1=="" & X2=="" & X3=="" & X4=="" & X5=="" & X6=="")) %>%
  
  # Sometimes `Secteur/Chefferie /Commune` and `Nom du site de vote` concatenate under X2 - Take last word X2 and assign it to X3
  mutate(last_piece = case_when(X3=="" & X1!="" ~ word(X2, start = -1))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
         mutate(X3 = if_else(X3=="" & X1!="", last_piece, X3))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
         mutate(X2 = if_else(!is.na(last_piece), str_remove(X2, last_piece), X2))) %>%
  select(-("last_piece")) %>%
  
  # Remove Empty Columns
  select(-c("X11", "X12"))
```

Here is a selected extract of the output of this previous code:

```
structure(list(X1 = c("", "47", "", "", "22", "", "", "91", "", 
"", "93", "", "", "112", "", "", "113", "", "", "114", "", "", 
"117", "", "", "118", "", "", "19", "", "", "25", "", "", "91", 
"", "", "2", "", "", "25", "", "", "70", "", "", "71", "", "", 
"61", "", "", "98", "", "", "8", ""), X2 = c("", "TRIBUNAL 3IEME CHAMBRE WAKA BOKEKA", 
"A - BDE MONYEKA", "", "HOPITAL GENERAL DE LAC  NTOMBA", "A - BREFERENCE", 
"", "EP.NASURA", "", "", "E.P. MATARI", "", "", "E.P 4 LULENGELE", 
"", "", "E.P. 2 KONYI", "", "", "E.P. 3 LULENGELE", "", "", "E.P. LUBI", 
"", "", "E.P 1  KONYI", "", "", "E.P. 2 MAWETE BULUNGU", "", 
"", "ITM BULUNGU", "", "", "E.P. 2 LUTONDO KWENGE", "", "", "EP TCHAMBOMBO", 
"", "", "COMPLEXE SCOLAIRE BUHAVU", "A - HANAMAD", "", "EP RUMONDO", 
"", "", "EP. KATASOMWA", "", "", "E.P. KALAMA", "", "", "EP CHISHALI", 
"", "", "CENTRE DE SANTE BOBONGO  NZULU", "A - EI"), X3 = c("", 
"BUYA", "", "", "BESONGO II", "", "", "RUNGU", "", "", "MAYOGO-MABOZO", 
"", "", "LUEBO-LULENGELE", "", "", "LUEBO-LULENGELE", "", "", 
"LUEBO-LULENGELE", "", "", "LUEBO-LULENGELE", "", "", "LUEBO-LULENGELE", 
"", "", "", "", "", "BULUNGU", "", "", "TANGANGA", "", "", "BUHAVU", 
"", "", "BUZI", "", "", "BUHAVU", "", "", "BUHAVU", "", "", "LUINDI", 
"", "", "LUHWINDJA", "", "", "", ""), X4 = c("", "MONYEKA I", 
"", "", "NTONDO", "", "", "", "", "", "MAKONDAIMA", "", "", "BAKWA- TSHIMUNA BENA BALE", 
"", "", "BAKWA-KASUA BAKWA NGINDU", "", "", "BAKWA-KASUA TSHIOMBE BULULU", 
"", "", "BAKWA-KATAWA DIBAYA", "A - BLEMBALEMBA", "", "BAKWA-KATAWA BAJILA KASANGA", 
"ALEMBALEMBA", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "CAMP KIMVUKA", "", 
"", "ZIRALO", "", "", "", "", "", "MUBUKU", "", "", "MUBUKU", 
"", "", "IHANGA", "", "", "CHIBANDA", "", "", "CENTRE DESANTE", 
"BOBONGO I"), X5 = c("", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "Quartier ZINIA", 
"1", "", "Commune MAMBAYA, Route", "A - CAeroport Matari 1", 
"", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", 
"", "PAROISSE CATH. NOTRE", "A - EDAME DE FATIMA", "", "BOULEVARD KABILA,", 
"A - FQ/ILUNGA 1", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "", "BWISHA", "", 
"", "RUMONDO", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "II", "", "", 
"", ""), X6 = c("", "", "2", "", "", "2", "", "", "2", "", "", 
"3", "", "", "3", "", "", "3", "", "", "3", "", "", "2", "", 
"", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "6", "", "", "7", "", "NYALUGUSHA", 
"", "", "", "2", "", "", "1", "", "CHIRIMIRO", "", "", "LUKUNGA", 
"", "", "CHIBANDA  II", "", "", "", "1"), X7 = c("", "", "410 064", 
"", "", "410 342", "", "", "520 091", "", "", "520 100", "", 
"", "910 108", "", "", "910 109", "", "", "910 110", "", "", 
"910 113", "", "", "910 114", "", "", "5", "", "", "320 050", 
"", "", "320 098", "", "", "2", "", "", "8", "", "", "4", "", 
"", "2", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "5"), X8 = c("", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "A - B", "", "", "", "", "", "A - C", 
"", "", "A - C", "", "", "A - C", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "320 044", "", "", "", "", "", "A - G", "", "", "7", "", 
"", "620 595", "", "", "620 640", "", "", "7", "", "", "4", "", 
"", "3", "", "", "440 008"), page = c("60", "60", "60", "70", 
"70", "70", "250", "250", "250", "250", "250", "250", "387", 
"387", "387", "387", "387", "387", "387", "387", "387", "387", 
"387", "387", "387", "387", "387", "879", "879", "879", "880", 
"880", "880", "887", "887", "887", "1571", "1571", "1571", "1573", 
"1573", "1573", "1577", "1577", "1577", "1578", "1578", "1578", 
"1585", "1585", "1585", "1588", "1588", "1588", "1682", "1682", 
"1682"), Plage = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A - B", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "A - C", NA, NA, "A - C", NA, NA, "A - C", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A - G", 
NA, NA, "A - G", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A - D", NA, NA, "A - G", 
NA, NA, "A - D", NA, NA, "A - C", NA, NA, NA), `Code SV` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "520 091", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "910 108", 
NA, NA, "910 109", NA, NA, "910 110", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "320 098", NA, NA, "620 646", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "620 640", NA, NA, "620 641", NA, NA, "620 393", 
NA, NA, "620 430", NA, NA, NA), `Nbre BVD` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "3", NA, NA, "3", NA, 
NA, "3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "7", NA, NA, "7", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "4", NA, NA, "7", NA, 
NA, "4", NA, NA, "3", NA, NA, NA), `Nbre CV` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "2", NA, NA, "2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, "2", 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-57L))
```

And here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
structure(list(N = c(47L, 22L, 91L, 93L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 117L, 
118L, 19L, 25L, 91L, 2L, 25L, 70L, 71L, 61L, 98L, 8L), Nom.du.site.de.vote = structure(c(19L, 
17L, 16L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 18L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 13L, 
15L, 9L, 12L, 1L), .Label = c("CENTRE DE SANTE BOBONG I", "COMPLEXE SCOLAIRE ANAMAD", 
"E.P 1  KONYI", "E.P 4 LULENGELE", "E.P. 2 KONYI", "E.P. 2 LUTONDO", 
"E.P. 2 MAWETE", "E.P. 3 LULENGELE", "E.P. KALAMA", "E.P. LUBI", 
"E.P. MATARI", "EP CHISHALI", "EP RUMONDO", "EP TCHAMBOMBO", 
"EP. KATASOMWA", "EP.NASURA", "HOPITAL GENERAL DE REFERENCE", 
"ITM BULUNGU", "TRIBUNAL 3IEME CHAMBRE DE MONYEKA"), class = "factor"), 
    Secteur.Chefferie.Commune = structure(c(11L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 9L
    ), .Label = c("BUHAVU", "BULUNGU", "KWENGE", "LAC  NTOMBA", 
    "LUEBO-LULENGELE", "LUHWINDJA", "LUINDI", "MAYOGO-MABOZO", 
    "NZULU", "RUNGU", "WAKA BOKEKA"), class = "factor"), Groupement.Quartier = structure(c(6L, 
    5L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 7L, 11L, 
    11L, 9L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("", "BAKWA- TSHIMUNA", "BAKWA-KASUA", 
    "BAKWA-KATAWA LEMBALEMBA", "BESONGO II", "BUYA", "BUZI", 
    "CHIBANDA II", "IHANGA", "MAKONDAIMA", "MUBUKU", "TANGANGA", 
    "ZIRALO"), class = "factor"), Adresse..Village.Avenue. = structure(c(13L, 
    14L, 17L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 19L, 11L, 1L, 16L, 4L, 6L, 15L, 5L, 
    18L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("BAJILA KASANGA", "BAKWA NGINDU", 
    "BENA BALE", "BOULEVARD KABILA, Q/ILUNGA", "BWISHA", "CAMP KIMVUKA", 
    "CENTRE DESANTE BOBONGO I", "CHIBANDA II", "CHIRIMIRO", "Commune MAMBAYA, Route Aeroport Matari", 
    "DIBAYA", "LUKUNGA", "MONYEKA I", "NTONDO", "NYALUGUSHA", 
    "PAROISSE CATH. NOTRE DAME DE FATIMA", "Quartier ZINIA", 
    "RUMONDO", "TSHIOMBE BULULU"), class = "factor"), Nbre.CV = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), Nbre.BVD = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 5L), Code.SV = structure(c(4L, 
    5L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 6L), .Label = c("320 044", "320 050", 
    "320 098", "410 064", "410 342", "440 008", "520 091", "520 100", 
    "620 393", "620 430", "620 595", "620 640", "620 641", "620 646", 
    "910 108", "910 109", "910 110", "910 113", "910 114"), class = "factor"), 
    Plage = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "A - B", 
    "A - C", "A - D", "A - E", "A - F", "A - G", "A - H"), class = "factor"), 
    Page = c(60L, 70L, 250L, 250L, 387L, 387L, 387L, 387L, 387L, 
    879L, 880L, 887L, 1571L, 1573L, 1577L, 1578L, 1585L, 1588L, 
    1682L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: So - this is a complex, interesting and time consuming problem. I cannot provide you full answer, as there are aspects that I do not quite understand. In any case, if it were my, I would start by collapsing the rows and work my way through it with `regex`-magic. You could start by `data %>% group_by(X1) %>% summarise(across( #.cols = -"X1",.fns = ~ paste(., collapse = ",")))`