# Conditionally Remove First Letter String if Equals Column

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I conditionally remove the first letter of a string variable if that letter equals another column?

In the example below I want to remove the A in `Plage` that is next to AKANGO in X3. If `Plage`equals NA or is blank I don't want to touch anything in X3.

Here is what I was thinking using, but it is not quite correct:

```
extractstack2 <- extractstack %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character),
         mutate(X3 = str_remove(substring(X3, 1, 1), `Plage`)))
```

```
structure(list(X1 = c("46", "", "", "47", "", ""), X2 = c("CABANE de BONGBATIA", 
"", "", "CABANE DE BONDINGIMA", "", ""), X3 = c("BARISSI-MONGINGITA-B BONGBATIA", 
"AAKANGO", "", "BARISSI-MONGINGITA-B BONGBATIA", "AAKANGO", ""
), X4 = c("BOZALI", "", "", "BONDINGIMA", "", ""), X5 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), X6 = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), X7 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), X8 = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), X9 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), X10 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), page = c("40", "", "", "40", "", 
""), X11 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), X12 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    Plage = c(NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA), `Code SV` = c(NA, "510 082", 
    NA, NA, "510 083", NA), `Nbre BVD` = c(NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", 
    NA), `Nbre CV` = c(NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: This `mutate(df, X3 = ifelse(!is.na(Plage), str_remove(X3, Plage), X3))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

regex to anchor the start and then just removing it

```
extractstack %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(X3 = gsub(paste0('^', Plage),'', X3))
```

Comment: when I add your solution to the code everything becomes very very slow:   # Remove First Letter from X2 and X3 in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609591/cleaning-extract-tables-conditional-merge-rows-systematic-extraction

Comment: try adding an `ungroup()` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove first letter in `X3` column if it is equal to `Plage` ?

Try -

```
library(dplyr)

extractstack %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character), 
         X3 = if_else(substring(X3, 1, 1) == Plage, sub('^.', '', X3), X3, missing = X3))
```

Comment: I think you need to handle the case, when `Plage` is `NA` and `X3` isn't.

Comment: If `Plage` is `NA` then it would keep `X3` value as it is, right?

Comment: That's my understanding of OPs requirement.

Comment: Yes exactly if ```Plage``` is ```NA``` keep ```X3``` value. Unfortunately it seems that @RonakShah's code removes what's in X3.

Comment: @MarcelCampion You can use `if_else` and `missing` argument in it to handle that case. See the updated answer.